# Why are tons of packages added when I reference a .NET Standard NuGet from within .NET 461?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I have a .NET 461 project that references a NuGet targeting .NET Standard 1.6.

As i've understood [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618222/2874896), referecing this NuGet will cause my .NET 461 projects packages.config to look like the following:

```
<packages>
   ...
   <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net46" />
   ...
</packages>
```

Actually, it looks more like this (there's like atleast 10 more that I haven't included here for simplicity):

```
<packages>
   ...
   <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net46" />
   <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" /> 
   <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" />
   <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" /> 
   ...
</packages>
```

Is it `NETStandard.Library` that automagically references all these? I cannot find any information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the recent improvements where packages we're moved from being referenced in `packages.config` to being referenced in project files was that they could implement a change wherein only your *direct* project dependencies are included in the file. Packages that *those* dependencies rely upon do not appear in the project file.

However, your snippet suggests that you're still using a `packages.config` file - in which case all dependencies in the transitive closure get included in the file, unfortunately, for backwards compatibility reasons.

Which specific packages you directly referenced (and which of those caused a particular package to appear in the packages.config due to a dependency) aren't recorded in this file.